# Very slow Windows XP Install on HP Pavilion DV9205US

Tags: windows-xp, installation, hp-pavilion

I'm busy installing XP on an HP Pavilion DV9205US, but it has been busy on the `Installing Windows` step, with 39 minutes remaining, for about an hour, if not more.  Changes in the HDD light indicate activity, but what activity could take so long?  This is with 2 GB RAM on a newly formatted 100 GB HDD.

**Update:**  It's time for a TV break, so I'm going with @Molly's suggestion below.

**Update:** So, just wanting to see the install underway before TV, my last one was greeted with a fatal error:

> One of the components that Windows needs to continue setup cannot be installed.  Error performing inpage operation. etc"

The End: I replaced the master (only) hard drive and everything since the install, including the install, has been mega-fast, faster than this machine has ever been before.

Comment: Does it say anything above the white/green progress bar, bottom-left?

Comment: That isn't on yet, just the 'scrolling lights' at the bottom right, which keep stopping then moving etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"I'm busy installing XP on an HP Pavilion dv9205us, but it has been busy on 
the Installing Windows step, with 39 minutes remaining, for about an hour, 
if not more."
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Load the BIOS factory defaults (or Fail Safe) and start again.

I don't think it is related to the controller settings ([AHCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface)) because you would not have gotten that far, however, if possible set it to IDE.

Comment: My BIOS has eerily few settings.  Just about the whole lot are date, boot order, and boot enablings.

Comment: that's HP/Compaq for ya. other than that, open the memory hatch and re-seat the RAM module ... another shot in the dark.

Comment: After restoring defaults I now have disk and DVD activity, one better than last time :-)

Comment: i'll keep my fingers crossed :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not unusual at all.  There is a ton of stuff going on.  Whenever I get to that step I just walk away and come back.  If you've got disk activity you're good.  Just let it wait.

Comment: there's 'a ton of stuff going on' at that point alright, but even an old Pentium III wouldn't take 1 hour at this stage. :)

Comment: Yeah @Molly, but that HDD is doing something.  Right?

Comment: sure, but after an hour or more i don't think it's going anywhere.

Comment: Oh yes, I've had it last more than an hour.

Comment: I just replaced the hard drive and that phase took about 5 minutes.  It's really moving now.

Answer (score 0):

My friend had a problem similar to yours on another HP (I don't know the model) and the install process took at least 2 hours on the second pass. The first install, I had stopped after it set for an hour, but the second time, I let it run.

Perhaps just let it go and do it's thing before making any changes.